# Why am I getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:" when I post form to a servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

Good day, in my simple test webapp project I have this Test.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/testCaptureParts" method="post">
        <textarea id="inputxml" name="inputxml" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It generates this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/TestApp/testCaptureParts" method="post">
        <textarea id="inputxml" name="inputxml" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The /TestApp/testCaptureParts is a servlet that implements doPost() method.

When I submit the form, I'm getting following exception even before servlets's doPost() method is called:

```
I 30, 2014 11:05:36 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TestCapturePartsServlet] in context with path
[/TestApp] threw exception
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: captureParts
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cz.test.servlet.TestCapturePartsServlet.doPost(TestCapturePartsServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to hardcode the URL as:

```
http://127.0.0.1/TestApp/testCaptureParts
```

But then when I submit the form in Mozilla it opens the "SaveAs" dialog saying "You opened testCaptureParts. It's application/octet-stream. What do you want to do?".
If I submit it Internet Explorer it opens a blank page with some unreadable characters.

```
á`Fžű^Čůňţđba`°ÁÍÖKâ×­C´
Á6đMäĎ¬?ye(lĐ§ĄŻÂ
ÉfDĺŇ›Áţ×ś]ęÓhą–ŹôŐ
@±.GLMC©°ľf`qpP
```

Please advise, how can I post the form to a servlet for further processing? Thank you in advance.

EDIT - This is the servlet class:

```
public class TestCapturePartsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        doPost(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException  {
        String inputxml = httpRequest.getParameter("inputxml");
        httpResponse.setContentType("text/plain"); 
        PrintWriter out = httpResponse.getWriter();
        try {
           String s = "Servlet response.";
           out.println(s);
           out.println("Parameter value = " + inputxml);
        } finally {
           out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

1. When I open URL in the browser as a GET request I'm getting expected text response.
2. When I POST the form from the browser to the URL I'm getting the "application/octet-stream" stuff.
3. When I POST some data from the RESTClient to the URL I'm getting expected text response.

I switched to the debugging mode and I set the breakpoint on the first line of the doPost() method. The execution stops for points 1 and 3 on the breakpoint. But for point 2 it doesn't, it looks like doPost() method is not called at all.

Comment: Seeing the code of that servlet (or at least its doPost method where at first sight it goes wrong) would probably be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Unless you want to do special stuff with the servlet's output, using a Writer is a lot easier.
2. You're not announcing an output type via setContentType, so the browser has to make a wild guess concerning the nature of the data you're throwing at it.

At its simplest, and using the recommendations above, your method could look like this

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // read the parameter that got passed
    String inputxml = request.getParameter("inputxml");
    response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
       String s = "Servlet response";
       out.println(s);
       out.println("parameter value = " + inputxml);
    } finally {
       out.close();
    }
}
```

Note: a servlet can use either the OutputStream **or** the PrintWriter, not both.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I updated my question.

Comment: Hmmm odd.  A bit of a long shot, but could you try calling it with `<form action="testCaptureParts" method="post">` and see what happens then?

Comment: I feel ashamed. I did not notice I miss port number in the URL. It should be http://127.0.0.1:8080/TestApp/testCaptureParts. Now it works. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Vojtech these things happen :)  Good luck with your project